# physical memory exceeding limits

Tags: apache-spark

Below is my spark submit

```
spark2-submit --class my.class \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--queue queue-name\
--executor-memory 10G \
--driver-memory 20G \
--num-executors 60 \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4G \
--conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=480 \
$HOME/myjar.jar param1 param2 param3
```

Error

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 50 in stage 27.0 failed 4 times, 
most recent failure: Lost task 50.4 in stage 27.0 (TID 20899, cdts13hdfc07p.rxcorp.com, executor 962): 
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 962 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 
15.7 GB of 14 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

My questions

1. I am assigning 10G of executor memory, from where 14 GB is coming?
2. I already mentioned 4G which is 40% of executor memory but still recommendation is to increase overhead memory

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned 10gb to each spark executor, you will need to ensure that there are enough resources on the machine/node running the executors for its other needs